# What are the reasons of failure to compute cache key: "/ng-app/dist" not found?

Tags: angular, typescript, dockerfile

Good Day!

In my Angular application , I have my docker file running, so while docker build of my application in visual studio, the below error pops up

Which displays COPY FROM  [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html:

failed to compute cache key: "/ng-app/dist" not found: not found

Any suggestions or idea our welcome.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because your `/dist` wasn't there. change to relate might help.  (change from `/ng-app/dist` to `./ng-app/dist`)

Comment: Thanks @paranaaan for your suggestion but there is something in my angular code that had error. After debugging the frontend code . It seems to work fine.